# Return max value from group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a view which will return APPROVER based on the highest sum of Nett. I can return a sum of the nett values but there are instances where multiple 'Codes' are used, therefore my view can return 2 or more rows. The requirement is to return the APPROVER based on the higest Nett.

Here's my view:

```
CREATE VIEW UDF_APPROVER
AS
WITH UDF_BUDGAPPROVER (_ID  , USERID , Nett , ANALYSIS)
AS
(
ISNULL(HEADER_PRIMARY,0) '_ID',
INITIATOR_ID as 'USERID',
SUM(NETT) AS 'Nett',
ANALYSIS 
FROM ORDER_HEADER
JOIN ORDER_DETAIL ON HEADER_PRIMARY = HEADER_LINK
GROUP BY
HEADER_PRIMARY,
INITIATOR_ID
ANALYSIS
)

SELECT
Nett ,
__PR_ID ,
__USER_ID ,
NCATEGORYCODE5 AS 'APPROVER' ,
CODE ,
FROM GENERAL_ACCOUNTS
JOIN UDF_BUDGAPPROVER ON CODE = ANALYSIS
WHERE _ID = 15
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUvQ9.png)

The GUI will pass in _ID so it will always only return the DETAIL rows that I want.

I need to return a single row to return the APPROVER as TR01 because 1-2102-60 has the highest Nett.

I think that I will need to go down the route of using a function.

I hope this makes sense, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: please check here on how to improve the question...https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Post some sample data and your expected output.

Comment: That might be tricky because it's client data. From the screenshot attached I only want to see APPROVER on row 1.

There are 3 tables involved, the order header (1 row), detail lines (1 or more rows) that contain the money values and analysis. Table 3 contains the APPROVER, analysis is used to join to the table on Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
CREATE VIEW UDF_APPROVER
AS
WITH UDF_BUDGAPPROVER (
    _ID
    ,USERID
    ,Nett
    ,ANALYSIS
    )
AS (
    ISNULL(HEADER_PRIMARY, 0) '_ID'
    ,INITIATOR_ID AS 'USERID'
    ,SUM(NETT) AS 'Nett'
    ,ANALYSIS FROM ORDER_HEADER
    JOIN ORDER_DETAIL ON HEADER_PRIMARY = HEADER_LINK
    GROUP BY HEADER_PRIMARY
        ,INITIATOR_ID ANALYSIS
    )
SELECT MAX(Nett) AS Nett
    ,__PR_ID
    ,__USER_ID
    ,NCATEGORYCODE5 AS 'APPROVER'
    ,CODE
FROM GENERAL_ACCOUNTS
JOIN UDF_BUDGAPPROVER ON CODE = ANALYSIS
WHERE _ID = 15
GROUP BY __PR_ID
    ,__USER_ID
    ,NCATEGORYCODE5
    ,CODE
```

Comment: I don't think that will work because APPROVER isn't distinct and therefore I can't group by it.